# JQuery toggle only related div closest to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have sets of similar divs that I am toggleing with some basic code like this:

```
 $(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function()
            {
        $(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
   });
```

The issue I am having is that whenever I trigger the "+", it toggles all other divs with the same class when I only want to toggle the related div closest to it `.field-group-format-wrapper` . I tried .next and .closest but that just seems to lock things up and then it does not work yet I am getting no syntax error e.g.

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function()
                {
            $(".field-group-format-wrapper").closest().toggle();
       });
```

I created a working version here but if you add in .closest as I have above, it does not work anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHguJ/5/

** Note, I only want to show / hide what's in `field-group-format-wrapper` and nothing else so the "Title" still needs to show whether expanded or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).  And use this to refer to the clicked element.  You were using closest which looks for the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) 'parent'.

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHguJ/11/

Comment: Interesting but that hides everything. I probably should have been more specific, I only want to hide what's in `field-group-format-wrapper` and nothing else so the "Title" still needs to show whether expanded or not.

Comment: @DannyEnglander Sorry was a mistake from copy and pasting your code.  I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nextAll()` like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swNLr/)

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(this).parent().find(".field-group-format-wrapper")`

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHguJ/12/

​Or with `siblings`:

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
});
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/LHguJ/13/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
    $(this).html( $(this).html() == '+' ? '–' : '+');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/JLj2X/

Comment: @DannyEnglander Note the edit times. My solution was completed before the accepted answer. :)