# JQuery testing if an element is visible or hidden and then add remove classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, visibility, hidden

I have a div that starts off on page load hidden. When I toggle the "+" element, the relative div toggles to visible. I am trying to add a class based on is(":hidden") or not with an if - else statement.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="views-row">
<div class="field-group-format-toggler-abstract">+</div>
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<div class="field-group-format-wrapper" style="display:none;">
Dolor minim neque pala ratis sit. Ideo odio praesent. Aliquam capto gravis quis. Antehabeo diam huic praemitto. Immitto pneum ratis vereor volutpat. Brevitas facilisis illum macto mos plaga ratis utrum. Jumentum rusticus secundum
</div>
</div>
```

and my JQuery is:

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function() {
$(this).nextAll(".field-group-format-wrapper").toggle();
               });

if($(".field-group-format-wrapper").is(":hidden"))
// this seems to work, 'closed' gets added
$('.field-group-format-toggler-abstract').addClass("closed");

// but this part does not seem to work     
     else
$('.field-group-format-toggler-abstract').addClass("open").removeClass("closed");
```

​This first part of this works but the add and remove class is not. I have tried variuos ways to do this but nothing seems to work, the class just remains on `closed`.

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHguJ/19/)**

Comment: How come you selected the `siblings()` answer to your earlier question but your implementation here it shows my answer which uses `nextAll()` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832405/jquery-toggle-only-related-div-closest-to-it/11832472#11832472

Comment: @Gabe, please bear with me, I am still experimenting with different implementations of code and what works best. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".field-group-format-toggler-abstract").click(function() {
    var $div = $(this).nextAll(".field-group-format-wrapper");  // <-- cache the selector
    $div.toggle();       
    $(this).toggleClass('open', $div.is(':visible')); // <-- if wrapper div is visible class open will be added // else it will be removed
    $(this).toggleClass('closed', $div.is(':hidden')); // <-- if wrapper div is hidden class open will be added // else it will be removed
});​
```

You are able to pass in a condition/switch to as a second argument in [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

http://jsfiddle.net/LHguJ/25/

Comment: haha, I just came to that conclusion myself after playing around with this for a few hours. Very nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
if($(".field-group-format-wrapper").is(":visible")){
  $('.field-group-format-toggler-abstract').addClass("close").removeClass("open");
}
else {
    $('.field-group-format-toggler-abstract').addClass("open").removeClass("closed");
}
```